Why does unity show error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'UnityEditorInternal' could not be found when i built and run?

I made a game in unity, it was finished when i try built and run it pop out this message"error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'UnityEditorInternal' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
"I tried to change external tools also my file got UnityEditorInternal.I was trying to find a solution for me to built and run my game

You're probably referencing editor functionality in your script, which you cannot use in a build. But we'd have to see the script to tell you where and what you can do about it.

When you build the game, the library containing UnityEditor is not deployed with it, you cannot use any functionality of it outside of the editor itself.

What tutorial need to use UnityEditorInternal?

You likely need to move any script for editor control into an Editor folder

Given the code you've posted, if you're editor is correct, you're not using the first few imported assemblies at all. So you can delete the first 4 lines of your script and try again.

I guess you are trying to use an editor code in runtime. Editor codes can't be used in runtime. If you can share the script that using UnityEditorInternal class, we can help you better.

I have already solve the problem, but still thank you for your attention.
